# "Salesforce1 simulator" for Moblie in Chrome Browser

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

I just found "Salesforce1 simulator" from google chrome App store. And for me it looks exactly similar to the App Salesforce1 provided by Saleforce and works perfectly fine as a Mobile App for My DEV ORG.

Anyone used this tool/App before? Can we trust it as a safe one and Can we use this in Multiple Environments - Prod/Sandbox(can see another APP for Sandbox itself)/DEV etc? Can we use this for both Android/Windows/IOS mobile App testing? Any limitation that we need to consider?

Any help is appreciated? Attaching a screen shot of this Simulator from my browser as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is completely safe and no limitation is there as far i know.

Since we test our app in sandbox, in sandbox we  don't have actual data then we can use this app for testing.

FYI: There are 2 version of this app, 1 for production/developer org and another for sandbox.